# how to make git push origin --force ; in Visual Studio Team Explorer

Tags: git, visual-studio, team-explorer

I recently had an issue where I had to disregard my last commit, so on the command line I did following:

```sh
git push origin --force
```

this works fine, however I normally make my push/pulls from inside Visual Studio Team Explorer, however I could not find out how to --force a push from there

Is it possible or can it only be done from command line?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can enable --force without using command prompt in visual studio 2017 as follows Open team explorer.

> Team Explorer>Settings>Git>Global Settings

check the enable push --force checkbox and that should do the trick like so [image: Check box]

For more info check out this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/03/06/new-git-features-in-visual-studio-2017/)

PS. **This feature is only available in visual studio 2017+ **

Comment: Yes but this is then done on the project all the time - what I was looking for was a way to only do it on some push, afterall using --force is not something which should be done unless you really know what your a doing.

Comment: Aggreed but, if you want to use it one some push you should just use command prompt for that specific push.

Comment: Enabling that checkbox does not do push --force all the time.  If enabled, VS will check to see if a force push is necessary based on the state of the remote tracking branches.  If it detects that a force is necessary, it will prompt you to be sure that is your intention.  It will then do "git push --force-with-lease" in order to be careful in case anyone else had pushed to that remote branch since your last fetch.  Hope this helps!

Comment: After enabling, you still can't push from the Synchronization section in Team Explorer, you have to go to the Branches section and right click the branch and push from there.

Comment: In addition to pushing from the Branches section, you can also "Push" from the branches drop-down in bottom right and you will be prompted if "force" is enabled.

Comment: force push all you want, the sane approach is to manage force push privledges at the repository level

Answer (score 31):

It's now (as of VS2019) in `Settings -> Source Control -> Git Global Settings`:

[image: Git Settings]

[image: Git force push settings]

Comment: Above is also valid for Visual Studio 2022.